# Change a style of a paragraph with picture

Tags: vba, image, ms-word

I am struggling with the following problem. 
In a document I have many inline pictures as well as some floating pictures.
I would like to write a code which **changes the style of a paragraph in which a picture is included**. Let's call this style "picture". The only problem is with **paragraphs floating pictures**, i.e., the ones which have picture with some text around. In this case I would like to leave the style untouched.

Here is the example of how it looks like in Word.

[image]

I have written such a code so far:

```
Sub ApplyPictureStyle()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim iShp As InlineShape
For Each iShp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
  With iShp
    If .Type = wdInlineShapePicture Then .Range.Style = "Picture"
  End With
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

As I explained earlier such a code will work for all pictures.

Is it possible to rewrite this code so that it works for **inline pictures but omits floating pictures** at the same time?

Comment: It's not clear from the image in the question under what circumstances the code is affecting the wrong paragraphs. We can't see where the inline shapes vs. the shapes are. Are we to assume that certain paragraphs have both inline shapes as well as the anchors of shapes?

Comment: Looking at the screenshot in your question I suspect that all of the pictures are inline shapes. An inline shape is one formatted with a wrap type of inline. Your code only applies to shapes of that type. I suspect that what you are actually trying to do is apply a style to paragraphs that only contain an inline picture and no text. Is that correct?

Comment: @CindyMeister
Can you tell me what's the difference between inline shape and anchor of shape.
All the pictures are **simply inserted**: 
- the first one is only the picture in the paragraph.
- the second one is the picture among the text in the paragraph.

How would you differ those two cases in VBA?

Comment: I agree with Timothy, those look like they're inline. When pictures are inline with text, their position is affected by paragraph formatting, The picture that's by itself in the paragraph has no distinguishing characteristics that make it different from the one that has text around it. So you code will have to find each picture, then test if there is text before or after, then apply any paragraph formatting.

Comment: If you had floating pictures, then they would be anchored to a paragraph, but the paragraph formatting would only affect the picture indirectly (i.e. if it was positioned relative to the paragraph, it would move when the paragraph did).

Comment: @JohnKorchok 
OK, Thank You. So I have to test whether a picture has a text around my picture.
But how to determine it in a code. How to determine that a picture is inside a text in a paragraph? I would like to use REGEX but I do not know what are the symbols for pictures in word.

Comment: Cross-posted - and answered in detail long before posting here - at: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?66708-Macro-for-setting-one-style-of-all-pictures&p=398839#post398839 . Perhaps you'd care to explain why you didn't have the courtesy even to acknowledge the answer you'd already received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A floating picture is one that doesn't have a wrap style of "Inline with Text". All of the pictures in your screenshot are inline pictures. So to apply different formatting to these pictures you need to determine whether the paragraph only contains a picture or a picture plus text.

You can do this by using the `Len` function to count the characters in the paragraph's text. A paragraph that only contains a picture will just have 2 characters, even if the picture has alternate text.

```
Sub ApplyPictureStyle()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim iShp As InlineShape
  For Each iShp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    With iShp
      If .Type = wdInlineShapePicture Then
        If Len(.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text) = 2 Then
          'paragraph only contains a picture
          .Range.style = "Picture"
        End If
      End If
    End With
  Next
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```